# When using Sinon, how to replace stub function in a stub instance?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, nodeunit

If I have create a instance by  `var a = sinon.createStubInstance(MyContructor)`.

How can I replace one of the stubbed function like `var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);`.

The main reason I am doing this is want to achieve multiple callback workaround as [this mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818811/sinon-js-stub-can-you-call-more-than-one-callback-on-a-single-stubbed-function)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The method you mentioned (`sinon.stub(object, "method", func)`) is a method that was available in version **1.x**, and did the following according to the documentation:

> Replaces `object.method` with a `func`, wrapped in a spy. As usual, `object.method.restore()`; can be used to restore the original method.

However, if you're using `sinon.createStubInstance()`, all methods are already stubbed. That means you can already do certain things with the stubbed instance. For example:

```js
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
}

const p = sinon.createStubInstance(Person);
p.getName.returns("Alex Smith");

console.log(p.getName()); // "Alex Smith"
```

If you really want to replace a stub by another spy or stub, you could assign the property to a new stub or spy:

```js
const p = sinon.createStubInstance(Person);
p.getName = sinon.spy(function() { return "Alex Smith"; }); // Using a spy
p.getName = sinon.stub(); // OR using a stub
```

With Sinon.js **2.x** and higher, it's even easier to replace a stubbed function by using the `callsFake()` function:

```js
p.getName.callsFake(function() { return "Alex Smith"; });
```

Comment: Before one calls, a.method = sinon.stub(), it is important to call a.method.restore().

Comment: Up-voted as this answer got me on the right track. Although since this was answered `sinon.stub(object, "method", fn)` has been deprecated. We can now use `sinon.stub(object, "method").callsFake(function() { // do stuff });` See [here](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.1/stubs#stubcallsfakefakefunction)
_Edit: fixed url_

Comment: @PhilD. You're right, but the question itself is asking for `sinon.stub(object, "method", fn)`, so I think I won't be including that information in the answer itself.

Comment: @g00glen00b, yes, but it takes everyone who comes here an extra iteration, to go back to code, learn that there is no third argument, return here for comments or dig deeper. I think everyone would benefit from an update section in the answer

Comment: @KirillSlatin Within the original state of this answer and the question I found it difficult to integrate it and still keep the answer on topic to the question. However, I tried to rewrite the answer so that I could integrate that part into my answer.

Comment: @g00glen00b thanks for update! It looks good to me. You could also add an **Update** section as it is natural that since you answered in 2015 API/library evolved and now there is a nuance to the proposed solution. It is comprehended properly by readers and a tradition on SO

Answer (score 14):

After stubbing a whole object using `sinon.createStubInstance(MyConstructor)` or `sinon.stub(obj)` you can only replace the stub by either assigning a new stub to the property (as described by @g00glen00b) or restoring the stub before re-stubbing.

```
var a = sinon.createStubInstance(MyConstructor);
a.method.restore();
sinon.stub(object, "method", func);
```

The advantage of this is that you can still call `a.method.restore()` afterwards with the expected behavior.

It would be more convenient if the Stub API had a `.call(func)` method to override the function being called by the stub after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to overwrite the `a.method`, instead we can use `callsFake` on the `a.method` directly:

```
const a = sinon.createStubInstance(MyContructor);
a.method.callsFake(func);
```

Comment: Used this approach and works like a charm. It's easier and clean!

Comment: Excellent, glad you like it!

Answer (score 2):

1 more way to stub the method  from 2.0 +

```js
sinon.stub(object, "method").callsFake(func);

object.method.restore()
```